# A* Pathfinding on Multiple Grids?

Tags: path-finding

I'm Working on a Base Building Game, with a Layer System like Dwarf Fortress. Where there are Multiple Grids Above each other

I Already have a Typical A* Pathfinding implementation, and it works fine on one grid but I dunno how to make it work with the other Grids

Most of my Problems comes from the Heuristics and the Stairs,
I just don't Know how to Calculate the Height for heuristics
and for the Stairs. I don't Know How to Make it Pick the Right Stairs that will Lead it too the Destination

Does anyone know exactly how to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you calculate the heuristic and what kind of graph do you use. Can you show some examples?

Comment: i think the graph is called grid graph, it's just a 3D array of a class called PathNode(which takes a X, Y and I, and a bool for if it's walkable, plus the gCost, hCost and fCost)
and for the heuristics well here's the functuation for calculating the distance cost

 private int CalculateDistanceCost(PathNode a, PathNode b) 
 {
        int xDistance = Mathf.Abs(a.x - b.x);
        int yDistance = Mathf.Abs(a.y - b.y);
        int remaining = Mathf.Abs(xDistance - yDistance);
        return MOVE_DIAGONAL_COST * Mathf.Min(xDistance, yDistance) + MOVE_STRAIGHT_COST * remaining;
}

Comment: if you want you learn more about the heuristics, here's the video where i took the pathfinding code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alU04hvz6L4&ab_channel=CodeMonkey
the only difference that i made is that i just added a 3D array and made it work with my own grid

edit: oh yeah, i also got rid of the diagonal Movement

Comment: Nowhere in your calculation you take the height into consideration. You should give your nodes three dimensional properties x,y,z every layer up will increment the z property. Than you do a 3d Manhattan distance calculation instead of 2D. Also take into account which points are accessible by which points.